# Unused area of laptop display while gaming

Tags: monitor, technical-issues

When I start playing a NFS Most Wanted or COD: Modern Warfare, I observed that the laptop screen is not used completely. There are 1.5 inches margins on both left and right ends of the screen that remain blank. The game is focused on the center. I've tried changing the resolution but it hasn't helped. Please advice on how I can make the games utilize the entire screen.

P.S: I have only tried playing the above-stated games.

Comment: It sounds like an aspect ratio problem. I'm just not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to look at alternate resolutions that match the aspect ratio of your display panel.  It's probably 16:9 or 16:10.  You may have tried other resolutions that don't match the ratio of your panel, which would explain the unused regions.

LCDs work best when you use their native resolution, which is generally given in the specifications for your laptop.  It's also likely that your Windows resolution is set to the native resolution of the panel; you can look at your display settings to check and see what this resolution is.  ([Here's](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Change-your-screen-resolution) how you'd do that on Windows 7)

Common resolutions for 16:9 are ([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/16:9)):

> 640x360, 854x480, 960x540, 1024×576, 1280×720, 1366×768, 1600×900, 1920×1080, 2048x1152, 2560×1440, 3840×2160 and 4096x2304.

Common resolutions for 16:10 are ([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/16:10)):

> 1280×800, 1440×900, 1680×1050, 1920×1200, and 2560×1600

The best idea is to use the native resolution given in your laptop's specifications, but trying one from each list will at least identify your panel as 16:10 or 16:9.

Comment: Tried this but it isn't working. Are there some settings in-game that I could try to modify ?

Comment: @fixxer Usually most games will let you set the resolution to what the laptop hardware supports. You may also want to check and see if there is an update for your graphics drivers.